# Badly placed ()'s when creating Xquery command

Tags: terminal, command, xquery, helper, docbook

So I have created the same books.xml file from W3schools. Now I'm trying to use Xquery.

I started with this command:   `doc("books.xml")`

but it shows the following error:

> Badly placed ()'s.

I have to use this query: `doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book/title`
But I get the same error

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Which XQuery implementation are you using and how are you calling it? Your XQuery is totally fine, as you're including "terminal" I'm guessing you're not escaping your query properly. If so, try to put some `'` around it.

Comment: Re: w3schools -- read http://www.w3fools.com to get an idea about the "usefulness" of w3schools.

Comment: I found the error, the Saxon file I've upload to my gl was not uploaded properly. I mean it was 3.9 MB but on gl it is 0 size !! So it works just fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

> I found the error, the Saxon file I've upload to my gl was not uploaded properly. I mean it was 3.9 MB but on gl it is 0 size !! So it works just fine now